# React impoting recharts failed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recharts

I'm trying to use [recharts](https://recharts.org/en-US) form a React project but I can't simply import components from it's library then using it.

I'm importing it within my package.json

`"recharts": "^2.0.9",`

and my index.js can't be lighter

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import {
  Radar,
  RadarChart,
  PolarGrid,
  PolarAngleAxis,
  PolarRadiusAxis,
  ResponsiveContainer,
} from 'recharts';

const info = {
  datas: [
    {
      subject: 'test1',
      A: 3,
      fullMark: 5,
    },
    {
      subject: 'test2',
      A: 5,
      fullMark: 5,
    },
    {
      subject: 'test3',
      A: 1,
      fullMark: 5,
    },
    {
      subject: 'test4',
      A: 0,
      fullMark: 5,
    },
    {
      subject: 'test5',
      A: 0,
      fullMark: 5,
    },
    {
      subject: 'test6',
      A: 0,
      fullMark: 5,
    },
  ],
  dataKeys: ['A'],
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <ResponsiveContainer height='100%' width='100%'>
    <RadarChart cx='50%' cy='50%' data={info.datas} outerRadius='80%'>
      <PolarGrid />
      <PolarAngleAxis dataKey='subject' />
      <PolarRadiusAxis />
      {info.dataKeys.map((dataKey, index) => (
        <Radar
          dataKey={dataKey}
          fill={info.fill || '#8884d8'}
          fillOpacity={0.6}
          key={index}
          name='Mike'
          stroke={info.stroke || '#8884d8'}
        />
      ))}
    </RadarChart>
  </ResponsiveContainer>,
  document.getElementById('radar')
);
```

This is the error message, habitually that happens when you miss the import but here it's the same as they mentioned in their doc.

> Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

followed by

> The above error occurred in the  component:
> at div
> at ResizeDetector (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:56892:24)
> at ResponsiveContainer (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:79234:5)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem.

You must indicate a fixed height for ResponsiveContainer.

So I changed this `<ResponsiveContainer height='100%' width='100%'>` to that `<ResponsiveContainer height={400} width='100%'>`.

The error is in their examples. ex: https://recharts.org/en-US/examples/SimpleRadarChart

Comment: I'm not sure this is (still) true (for all charts) because the docs show a working example without fixed height: https://recharts.org/en-US/examples